# How do I send html responsive email by outlook 2016?

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, web-frontend

I tried to paste html code into outlook under HTML format and press send button. But the email I received is an email with code. So what should I do to adjust the outlook 2016 to send an html email?

Comment: Can you also paste the code you have tried in your question?

Comment: **I don't know if this is possible.** There is [a related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076877/outlook-how-to-use-html-as-a-template-with-css), with comments.

Comment: Its not posible to send a responsive email thru outlook. You can insert the HTML as text which will show the email as it was designed but all media queries are changed for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook uses Word for rendering your HTML markup in Outlook. So, when you paste an HTML content into the editor it will be shown as a markup (try this in Word).

The simplest way is to use a VBA macro for setting up an HTML markup. You need to set up the [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941.aspx) property of the MailItem class to set the message body. Or you can use the Word object model for that. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found that interesting enough to skim the web and came to the conclusion, that you don't. Outlook will always mess with the included HTML if you don't take measures against the interference. Have a look at this article: https://www.mapilab.com/blog/insert-html-into-outlook-email-message/